# Spritekit changing parent makes the node disappear

Tags: sprite-kit, position, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have an SKScene with a node (big square) in the center. I have other nodes on it and I would like to change the parent of those to mySquare instead of the scene.

I tried using `myNode.moveToParent(mySquare)`. It seems to work as I can find my nodes under `mySquare` in the node tree (`for node in mySquare.children` print me the right nodes). My problem is that I do not see those nodes anymore...

I was wondering if the node could have the wrong position so I tried changing it's position with `node.position = mySquare.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: self)`. I tried putting the node's position in a temporary variable before the moveToParent and convert this position instead, it did not work. I then tried to simply position the node at the center of mySquare with `node.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` which is the anchor point of mySquare but the node still disappeared.

I tested the position by putting an SKEmitter on the node with sparks. The sparks are exactly where the node was when it's parent was the Scene, which means, at the right position. But the node is not there.

Would you have any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you very much for your time.

---

### Additionnal informations

This is how I created my node

```
let object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myObject")
self.addChild(copy() as! SKSpriteNote)
```

I set the position to match the touch (I create when I touch inside  mySquare).

mySquare is already in the scene from the beginning (I dragged an `SKShapeNode` in the scene editor which is a square).

This is where I change the parent

```
func sizeOfObject(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    if (sender.state == .Began){
        for nodes in nodesOnMySquare {
            let pos = table.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: self)
            node.removeFromParent()
            table.addChild(node)
            node.position = pos
        }
    }
```

In my for loop I also tested moveToParent, like this

```
node.moveToParent(table)  //Same result, the node disappear
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the zPosition of your Node. Maybe it is hidden behind another element.

Comment: I check this too, I tried putting a higher zPosition than any other node in the project, I still cannot see it.

Comment: OK, strange. And the size of your target node? Can you give us a small sample code?

Comment: Hmm. I cannot see where you use the object. It is only instantiated in your sample. Also the copy function is missing.

Comment: I added more infos. The copy function is not made by me (SKSpriteNode copy function).